# How to pass authorization and build role-based authorization in NativeScript using Angular

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, google-api, nativescript

From time ago I tried something new in programming, so I started to learn NativeScript and Angular. In case of that I'm building a cross platfrom mobile application which help people saves their lives and in case of that I want to build in my mobile app login via OAuth 2.0 using Google Account Provider, but I don't know how to give access to some functionalities in my app only for authorized users. I created OAuth login with Google provider and it's working fine. But when user is logged, authorization change status of "isAuthorized" flag to true. If I try to use this flag in other components, I received many errors related to reach "isAuthorized" flag. I tried many ideas and now I don't know how to pass it out to other components or maybe it's better solution for that case?

Here's the code of .html component which holds login button (this works fine)

```
<StackLayout row="0" class="nt-drawer__header">
 <Image class="nt-drawer__header-image fas t-36" src="font://&#xf2bd;"></Image>
 <Button class="google-signin" style="background-color: #30BCFF; color: #FFF; border-radius: 5; font-size: 20;" 
    *ngIf="isAuthenticated == false" 
    text="Zaloguj się z Google" 
    (tap)="onLogin()"></Button>
    <Button class="google-signout" style="background-color: #30BCFF; color: #FFF; border-radius: 5; font-size: 20;"
    *ngIf="isAuthenticated == true"
    text="Wyloguj"
    (tap)="onLogout()"></Button>
  <Label class="nt-drawer__header-footnote" 
    *ngIf="isAuthenticated == true" 
    text="{{ userEmail }}"></Label>
</StackLayout>
```

Here's the function which holds login function and described flag for login (also works fine)

```
import { IAuthenticated } from './interfaces/IAuthenticated'

@Component({
  selector: 'ns-app',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit, IAuthenticated {

  isAuthenticated: Boolean = false

  onLogin() {
    this.authService.tnsOauthLogin('google').then((_result: ITnsOAuthTokenResult) => {
      this.isAuthenticated = true;
      this.router.navigate(['/home']);
    })
    .catch((e) => console.log(e))
  };

  onLogout() {
    this.authService.tnsOauthLogout();
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
    this.router.navigate(['/home']);
  }
}

export function isLogged(): Boolean {
  return this.isAuthenticated ? true : false
}
```

Here's the function and html condition for component which not work

```
<StackLayout>
  <Button *ngIf="checkUserAuth() == true" text="Dodaj wpis"></Button>
</StackLayout>

import { isLogged } from '../app.component'

export class KnowledgeBaseComponent implements OnInit {

  ngOnInit(): void {
    isLogged()
  }

  checkUserAuth(): Boolean {
    return isLogged() ? true : false
  }
}
```

Also maybe someone knows that error regarding google api scopes?

"You are receiving this error either because your input OAuth2 scope name is invalid or it refers to a newer scope that is outside the domain of this legacy API."

Here's the configuration

```
export function configureOAuthProviderGoogle(): TnsOaProvider {
    const googleProviderOptions: TnsOaProviderOptionsGoogle = {
        openIdSupport: 'oid-full',
        clientId: ''
        redirectUri: ''
        urlScheme: ''
        scopes: ["openid", "email"]
    };

    const googleProvider = new TnsOaProviderGoogle(googleProviderOptions);

    return googleProvider;
}
```

Thanks for help and sorry for that long questions

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue I used SecureStorage plugin for NativeScript to make something like login session. Then I created a SecureStorage object, which holds data in key-value flow. So with every new login the application use SecureStorage object to create authorized key-value data and store it into the object. This is used to check in the specified component if user is logged and shared specified functionality. After performed logout function the object is deleted in case of that som functionalities could be hidden.

To make loggin session I use this code in my auth-service.ts

```
    tnsOauthLogin(providerType){
    this.client = new TnsOAuthClient(providerType)

    return new Promise<ITnsOAuthTokenResult>((resolve, reject) => {
        this.client.loginWithCompletion((tokenResult: ITnsOAuthTokenResult, error) => {
            if(error){
                console.log(error)
                reject(error)
            } else {
                this.secureStorage.set({
                    key: '',
                    value: ''
                }).then(success => console.log(success));
                resolve(tokenResult);
            }
        });
    });
}

tnsOauthLogout() {
    if (this.client) {
        this.client.logout()
        this.secureStorage.remove({
            key: ''
        }).then(success => console.log(success));
    }
}
```

Function which checked if user is logged in components

```
isLogged() {
 if (this.secureStorage.getSync({ key: '' })) {
    this.isAuthenticated = true;
 } else {
    this.isAuthenticated = false;
 }
}
```